# Will tcp retransmission have impact on other connection?

Tags: tcp

Say i have a server A having tcp retransmission between A and B, now if another client C talks to A (A -> C) there is no retransmission but will retransmission between A and B have impact on A and C channel?

Comment: Of course it will. It uses bandwidth too.

Comment: Define impact. It will definitively affect the available bandwidth seen by A -> C flow. But the A -> C flow does not know that this is due to retransmissions by A -> B.